# What features of a trail camera make it easier for photographing animals than other cameras?

Tags: terminology, electronic-gear, photography, trail-cameras

In [this answer](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/a/20393/5547) to a [question](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/20392/how-can-we-be-the-most-respectful-to-a-moose-when-photographing-it-up-close) I asked about how to photograph moose without scaring them, one of the possible suggestions was a "trail camera."

What exactly is a trail camera? How does it differ in the ability to photograph animals than any other camera I may already have? Does it have to do with size or shape, lens size or type, or other features that are unique?

Comment: @cobaltduck sites like StackExchange very frequently already have the answer.  Sites like TGO.SE or Pet.SE are trying ["to build a library of detailed answers to every question about outdoor activities".](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/tour) this question is not to broad.

Comment: Related https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/20415/how-to-keep-a-trail-camera-from-being-stolen

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Trail cameras are **motion sensitive cameras that are secured to trees or other objects to capture animals or people passing by on a trail.**

They look like this,

[image]

[Source](https://www.cabelas.com/shop/en/stealth-cam-px28ng-10mp-trail-camera-100128744?lcab.rdr=TRUE&slotId=1)

They have attachments for the straps and lights for a flash after dark, some will infrared pictures as well and video  and they are set up to trigger the pictures by motion, usually animals moving by although you have to be careful as branches moving in the wind can do it as well.

You end up with pictures like this,

[image]

[Source](https://www.pinterest.com/pin/568086940486578775/)

[image]
<sub>(source: [deerlab.com](https://deerlab.com/?ACT=25&f=first-trail-camera-photos__large.jpg&fid=2&d=47))</sub>

[Source](https://deerlab.com/blog/first-trail-camera-photos)